# Lua error -Bad argument #1 to remove

Tags: lua, lua-table

When i try to remove the object from table using the following coding it returns a Bad argument error,

**Code**

```
table.remove(tablesArr[currentTableObj[currentTableCode].tableId]["STATUS"], currentTableObj[currentTableCode].tableId)
table.insert(tablesArr[currentTableObj[currentTableCode].tableId]["STATUS"], currentTableObj[currentTableCode].tableId,tostring(currentTableObj[currentTableCode].status+1))
```

**Error**

```
Bad argument #1 to 'remove' (table expected, got string)
```

I knew the syntax of removing is

```
table.remove(tablesArr,currentTableObj[currentTableCode].tableId);
```

But i want to remove the exact value in

```
tablesArr[currentTableObj[currentTableCode].tableId]["STATUS"]
```

How to remove the index value in 2d array in lua,Please help to solve.

Comment: Doesn't error speaks for itself? And unless you show us what `tablesArr` is it's hard to tell anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to remove value just set it to `nil`:

```
tablesArr[currentTableObj[currentTableCode].tableId]["STATUS"] = nil
```